# SpringMVC Form Validation doesn't work properly

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have an issue with springMVC Form Validation .. I have an example in a project using maven and the same with gradle and when running each one , validation with gradle example work proberly but   not working proberly with maven.
any help  please?
I have attached the two projects
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BXEuBebHecHagYLGvuzX0yqBgw6u_t1C?fbclid=IwAR24x9D3oCtcp_awdX8sb7CEm_uK2Ngx93vMTPuy_-3gIMpJIl14TctLANo

Answer (score 0):

thanks , the problem wasn't from org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

sometimes when you apply auto import , it make a problems. the problem is because I missed Hibernate Validation from my POM file so , auto import include this

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
<artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
<version>RELEASE</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

which give a logical error (the validation doesn't work and go to next page even if condition not valid)

so the solution is to include this

```
<!-- Hibernate Validator -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and don't apply auto import in intellij

thanks